# Start with div hidden then toggle using Animate.css fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I am trying to make a div start out hidden using display: none and then use jQuery to toggle fadeIn animation from [Animation.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) from the click of a button.

But when i attempt to toggle the animation, it works but hiding it it doesn't play the fadeout animation.

here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/wilprim/pen/vabVzv):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="window animated"></div>

<button style="margin: 100px;">Toggle Fade Window</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.window{
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".window").toggleClass("fadeIn");
  })
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted is insufficient for creating a [mcve], which makes it impossible for anyone trying to help to experience/inspect the issue as well as testing any possible solutions for it. Do try to add a **runnable** example to your question.

Comment: I updated my question to include an example now

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems related to your code as well as your misunderstanding of the `animate.css` library:

- If you remove `fadeIn` from the `div`, it does not automatically fade out for you, you have to add class `fadeOut` in.
- `fadeIn` will make the `opacity` of the element from `0` to `1`, so with `display: none` in your CSS styling, it won't work.

This is the idea how you fix the problem:

- If the `div` doesn't have both `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` class when the button is being clicked, it means the div is in its initial state when you first render the view, so you need to add `fadeIn` class in.
- If the `div` does have `fadeIn` but `fadeOut` class when the button is being clicked, it means that previously the div has faded in and now, it needs to fade out. So, just remove `fadeIn` from the `div` and add `fadeOut` class.
- The last case is the reverse of the above case, you need to add `fadeIn` and remove `fadeOut` if the `div` has `fadeOut` class when the button is being clicked.

Here is the code

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(".window").hasClass("fadeIn")) {
      // if the div has fadeIn class, remove it and add fadeOut
      $(".window").toggleClass("fadeIn").toggleClass("fadeOut")
    }
    else if ($(".window").hasClass("fadeOut")) {
      // if the div has fadeOut class, remove it and add fadeIn
      $(".window").toggleClass("fadeOut").toggleClass("fadeIn")
    } else {
      // if the div has neither of fadeIn nor fadeOut, add fadeIn class in
      $(".window").toggleClass("fadeIn")
    };
  })
})
```

```css
.window{
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="window animated"></div>
<button style="margin: 100px;">Toggle Fade Window</button>
```